# Android, problems with TextView contents when drawing Layout into canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, xamarin, bitmap

I try to do a screenshot on Android, but for a part of the screen only (a Layout containing a few views).

Everything works fine except Textviews. As you can see below, the content of my Textview get cut off. I can't understand why.

Any help please ?

Here is what I need and what I have (first the real screenshot, second the bitmap created with my code).. As you can see, some textviews have missing text :(

Real screenshot :
[image]

Bitmap created by my code :
[image]

Here is my code AXML :

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_linearlayout_printScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork">
                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_linearlayout_sport">
                            <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_imageview_iconesport"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:maxWidth="42dp"
                                android:maxHeight="42dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_sport"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        map:mapType="normal"
                        map:liteMode="true" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_linearlayout_chrono" >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_chrono"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                            android:textSize="36sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_chrono_ms"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_distanceParcourue_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_distanceParcourue_desc"
                                android:text="@string/fragment_home_chronoMoovelive_textview_distanceParcourue_desc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_grisfonce"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_vitesseMoyenne_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_vitesseMoyenne_desc"
                                android:text="@string/fragment_home_chronoMoovelive_textview_vitesseMoyenne_desc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_grisfonce"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_rythme_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_rythme__desc"
                                android:text="@string/fragment_home_chronoMoovelive_textview_rythme_desc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_grisfonce"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_denivele_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_noire"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/activity_moovelive_textview_denivele_desc"
                                android:text="@string/fragment_home_chronoMoovelive_textview_denivele_desc"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/moovenow_grisfonce"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code that draw the layout into a canvas :

```
//Create the bitmap with the content of the view... full width / minimum height possible
                int iMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
                m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.Measure(iMeasureSpec, iMeasureSpec);

                Android.Util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new Android.Util.DisplayMetrics();
                WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);

                int iMeasuresWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;
                int iMeasuredHeight = m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.MeasuredHeight;

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(iMeasuresWidth, iMeasuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                bitmap.EraseColor(Color.Transparent);

                //Draw on canvas
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.Draw(canvas);
```

Thank you in advance for any help or advice ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround. Instead of creating the canvas with the method layout.Draw(Bitmap), I use the view's drawingCache. 
Follow this code :

```
        m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.BuildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap screenshotBitmap = m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.DrawingCache;

        //.... [save bitmap to file]

        m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.DrawingCacheEnabled = false;
        m_layoutPrintScreenAndShareToSocialNetwork.DestroyDrawingCache();
```